# ionic: using the framework with only HTML5

Tags: html, ionic-framework, hybrid

I'm thinking of using ionic for my project but in the beginning I'd like to only have a webapp without going to an app. Like what framework7 allows. But the information I gathered seems to indicate that this is not possible or fully supported by ionic.

Could someone share some experience to say if it's possible and how hard it is?

Comment: yes you can create web application but you cannot use plugins like toast, camera or etc

Answer (score 3):

For ionic2 it is possible:

1. add codova platform browser
2. upload files under platforms/browser/www
3. point it in browser

done

Note: Plugins that depends on device will not work in browser (for instance camera etc..), the rest will work fine, so keep your app usable even without device plugins

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to port your Ionic app as a mobile website.

Its basically an angular app with added benefits of Ionic ecosystem. This ecosystem includes nifty set of directives of mobile first ui components, js library for interactions (pull to refresh / slide etc) and other such things that compliments your app to make it look and feel like using a native app.

It really shines at accessing native components of your device (camera, location, battery info etc) using js apis (cordova.js). But it isn't of any use when you are building a mobile website with ionic. So, you could write platform specific code to support both web and native in conjunction. You could make the most of cordova.js when you start building your native apps. Else, leave it plain vanilla for your mobile site.

I have ported my ionic app as a web app to serve my audience on mobile browsers (also plan to roll out native apps soon) and I have not faced any major challenges so far. It truly has mobile first experience.

If making a single page desktop website is your sole objective, you should probably go for standard angular bootstrap web apps. Ionic isn't meant for it.