# Deploy Ionic as a website

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have created an ionic app and want to deploy it as a website. What's the best way to deploy it on a custom domain? I was thinking of using azure web app to host the ionic app. All the documentation refers to use it as hybrid app for IOS and Android. But at this point, we are only interested for it to function as a website.

Comment: Hope an Ionic app can be a frontend for ROR: [Serve Rails API and Ionic mobile website together](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36074227/serve-rails-api-and-ionic-mobile-website-together)

Comment: The other answers tell how to upload the content of the `build` folder to a web host, but that's not sufficient. The web server must be configured to load the `index.html` file on all targets. When you plainly serve the folder's content (like when using `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` on your local machine), it won't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**edit:** Ionic 1.2 officially [supports deployment as a website](http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/ionic/ionic-1-2-is-out/)!

As I stated in the comment to the only provided answer - **I disagree**.

If you're not using any Cordova plugins then there is no problem (if you really wish to) to upload the contents of the `www` folder to your server, and woila - you'll have the same app.

However, it is important to note that Ionic never intended for such a use, and the users of your "website" will have to have a newest browser in order to see the "website" correctly (not broken down due to some feature that Ionic is using in either CSS or HTML that some older browsers do not support).

You can take a look at [the tutorial](http://tutorials.pluralsight.com/review/how-to-create-a-calculator-application-with-ionic-framework-by-using-ionic-creator-for-ui/article.md) with step by step on how to recreate the application. I literally took out the contents of the `www` folder and put it on the web server, and as you can see it works.

Comment: It's nice. I sincerely never tested that without any Cordova plugins. That is why  i generally test my apps using Ionic View.

Comment: I tested it and that's why I replied to this. You can see this at work on this example: http://nikola-dev.com/IonicCalculator/mobile.html.

Comment: Interesting, but in a real app, i think would be hard to do something like this. Any more complex logic would break in the web version.

Comment: Again, I would have to disagree. This is nothing more than a simple AngularJS application that has styling from Ionic. Of course, one would have to make sure your users are using the latest browsers. All this I'm not talking out of the blue, we actually have a "web application" (over 20k LOC) that we developed with Ionic and deployed not as a mobile app but as a website. But yes, I agree with you that since Ionic said this is not per se meant to be used like this and it "might" break, that most users shouldn't do it. In our case it worked, but it wasn't a "simple" application.

Comment: `Any more complex logic would break in the web version.` More complex logic is more than just a styling. Use the same code you use in a Ionic app in a website is just crazy. You get limited, because you can't use Cordova plugins in the app because the website uses the same version and web won't support these plugins. You are using mobile components in a website, the UX is completely different. And just for using the components, there are many libraries (Bootstrap, Semantic, Foundation, etc). I don't think is right to consider a AngularJS application with the css of Ionic a Ionic app.

Answer (score 8):

It is a late answer, but as an official for Ionic 2:

> With Ionic 2 we are fully supporting the web (including eventual built
>   in support for Progressive web apps) as a platform right alongside
>   Android, IOS, Windows 10 and Electron. Thanks for using Ionic!

And

> If you are using certain Cordova plugins that only work on native
>   platforms then these will not work on the web, although if you are
>   using Ionic native they will fail gracefully. But if you stay away
>   from using those certain plugins, or write logic to provide an
>   alternative when on the web then it should work perfectly. Also, our
>   browser support includes Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Opera(since it's just
>   chrome nowadays), and Edge. We do not support any version of Internet
>   Explorer with Ionic 2. So basically, as long as you keep Cordova
>   plugins in mind, the same Ionic 2 project that works on your Android,
>   IOS or Windows 10 device will work just as well in the browser.
>   Thanks!

The source for this: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/7376

---

From my experience in Ionic 1, it is simple to work on a website, it is just copy/paste for `www` directory, actually, it does make sense, you are running AngularJS website! you could have a few errors and some of the functionalities not working (i mean the native plugins as for example `facebookConnect`) but you can handle it and run the web-specific version instead.

In our company, we do have an application work as a website with firebase, and mobile app with the same code, but you do need to write a few lines to handle web browsing side or mobile native call.

Answer (score 4):

For ionic2, add corbova browser platform, then upload to web server `platforms/browser/www`

Comment: This is what Im after. I just want to be able to upload the www/ to a webserver for client showing. It does not need to work interact with any plugins but just pure UI. Thanks for this

Answer (score 2):

Check my answer [ionic: using the framework with only HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32663231/ionic-using-the-framework-with-only-html5/32664764#32664764) on the idea of using it as a web application.

You could deploy it as static website on s3 and use your custom domain to point to s3. You can configure your s3 bucket to be used as a static website host. There are many tutorials on how to go about it.