# How to run Ionic serve permanently?

Tags: angularjs, linux, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic framework for one application. The code is on a linux server. I am running the application using `ionic serve` command through putty.

But, the problem is if I close the putty the application is stopped. Is there any way to run the ionic serve permanently as a daemon process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm suspecting you're trying to do this because you want to serve your Ionic app as a web app, correct?

In that case - you don't have to run `ionic serve` permanently. All you have to do is take all the code from the `www` folder and place it in the `http` folder (or any other which is valid for your system) of your web server.

So, basically, spin up apache (or nginx) and serve the code from the Ionic's `www` folder. Basically, `ionic serve` command does the same thing - it spins up a local web server and serves the content from the www folder. It does that for faster local testing.

You can take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33195748/deploy-ionic-as-a-website/33198389#33198389) for more info on how to deploy Ionic as a website.

Comment: Great, I'm glad the answer was helpful to you.

Comment: what if our javascript files uses node modules (3rd party libraries)? how do we deal with that?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to test on my server using Ionic and Capacitor but the www folder wasn't running the third party apps.

Although not tested, technically the setup should be able to work for Ionic with the other frameworks e.g Vue, React, etc.

Using `nginx` and `supervisor` I got it to work.

**Nginx config**

`sudo apt-get install nginx`

`sudo apt-get install nano`

Create a `conf` file

`sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/ionic`

Add the following inside the file.

```
server {
    listen 8100;
    server_name your-domain.com your-ip-address;

    charset utf-8;

    client_max_body_size 10M;

    #Django media and static files
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8101;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Note, I'm listening on port 8100 but you could use any other port e.g. 80. Also, `proxy_pass` is set to 8101 as ionic will be running on this port. See below under the Supervisor config

**Supervisor config**

`sudo apt-get install supervisor`

Then create a `conf` file

`sudo nano /etc/supervisor/conf.d/ionic.conf`

Add the following inside

```
[program:ionic]
command=ionic serve --port=8101
directory=/path/to/your/ionic/folder
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=3
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/ionic/error.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/ionic/out.log
```

As described earlier in the Nginx config, I'm serving ionic on port 8101.

Note: not get an error, create the ionic folder in the logs

`sudo mkdir /var/log/supervisor/ionic`

Then enable and restart the services

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/ionic /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
sudo systemctl restart nginx
sudo systemctl restart supervisor
sudo supervisord
```

Before opening your website, check that ionic is running on correct port in the log output file

```
tail -80 /var/log/supervisor/ionic/out.log

sudo systemctl enable supervisor
sudo systemctl enable nginx
```

`http://your-domain.com:8100` or `http://your-ip-address:8100`